# MongoDB returns collection, but the the length property is showing as 0

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js, express

I am a novice in express+mongo+backbone.
I am fetching data from mongodb via backbone collection.fetch(); in return I am getting the data but as you can see below  .length and models array is showing as 0 which is wrong. Because if I drill down, I can see all my documents/models.
What am I doing wrong here?
Below is my code at client side - backbone

```
var API = {
    getContactEntities: function () {
        var contacts = new Entities.ContactCollection();
        console.log("fetching data from database");
        contacts.fetch();
        console.log(contacts);
        if (contacts.length === 0) {
            // if we don't have any contacts yet, create some for convenience
            //return initializeContacts();
        }
        return contacts;
    }
};
```

Below is my code on server - express.js which is responding to fetch on url "/contacts"

```
//app.get('/contacts', appointments.allContacts);
exports.allContacts = function (req, res) {
    db1.db.users.find({}, function(err, appointments) {
        if (err) { res.json(err); }
        res.json(appointments);
    });
};
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, url: "contacts"…}
_byId: Object
c5: child
c6: child
c7: child
c8: child
__proto__: Object
_events: Object
_listenerId: "l4"
length: 4
models: Array[4]
0: child
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
_id: "52604e58d40340638c5e4b45"
address: Object
firstName: "Alen"
lastLogin: ""
lastName: "Wilkins"
phoneNumber: "555-0184"
pwd: ""
userId: "1"
userName: "chidu.murthy@gmail.com"
userStatus: "active"
userType: "admin"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c5"
collection: child
__proto__: Surrogate
1: child
2: child
3: child
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Surrogate
```

Could any of you explain whats wrong?

To completely rule out the behavior of MongoDB, I did just pass a json object as resonse but still the result is the same!!! so it has to be something with express or backbone

```
res.json(
        [
            { _id: 1, firstName: 'Alice_db', lastName: 'Arten',
                phoneNumber: '555-0184' },
            { _id: 2, firstName: 'Bob_db', lastName: 'Brigham',
                phoneNumber: '555-0163' },
            { _id: 3, firstName: 'Charlie_db', lastName: 'Campbell',
                phoneNumber: '555-0129' }
        ]
    )
```

Many Thanks in advance.

BR, Chidan

Comment: Post a code snippet, please. Is your server JSON response just a raw array of objects (not a wrapper object)?

Comment: Are you accounting for the fact that `fetch` is an AJAX call? Are you sure that you're waiting for the server to respond before trying to look at the data?

Comment: Hi Mu, Peter, I have added the code snippet

Comment: Hi Mu, I artificially introduced a delay of 2 secs, but the result is stil the same :(     setTimeout(function () {
                contacts.fetch();
            }, 2000);

Comment: `contacts.fetch();console.log(contacts.lenght)` is pretty much guaranteed to give you a zero because `fetch` is an AJAX call. Listen for events on `contacts`, the events will tell you when the server has responded to the AJAX call. Also watch the network panel in your browser's developer tools to see the JSON that is being sent back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most things you posted look OK. The `setTimeout` you did missed the point:

```
contacts.fetch();
//fetch is asynchronous. contacts is ALWAYS still going to be empty here
console.log(contacts);
contacts.on('sync', function () {
  //look, the 'sync' event has fired meaning the data is actually here now!
  console.log(contacts); 
});
```